# Compute the residue of $ 1/(\sin z) $ at $z=\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Exercise: 
>      Compute the residue of $ 1/(\sin z) $ at $z=\pi$

Sketch:
I tried to compute the residue at $z = 0$, because for $z = \pi$ it is the same. 
Taylor power series expansion around zero:
$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\ldots\implies\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)}=\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+\ldots\right)$$
It's correct solution?

Comment: Why do you think the residue at $z=0$ is the same as that at $z=\pi$? Sine is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Yeah the residue is $-1$. Note that all poles of sine are simple, so $\frac{(z-\pi)}{\sin{z}}$ is analytic at $\pi$ thus residue will be given by $\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{(z-\pi)}{\sin{z}}=-1$ [L'Hopital].

Comment: @Hrodelbert, yes, but if modify that $z = 2\pi$, this argument works?

Comment: Yes, then the argument works.

Comment: @gustaffIR why do you compute $(z-\pi)/\sin(z)$?

Comment: @Blabla If $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ then the residue is the constant term of in expansion of $(z-z_0)f(z)$. To see this just Laurent expand $f$ at $z_0$ and then multiply by the factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point $a$ is a simple pole of the function $f$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=l
$$
is finite and nonzero. In this case $l$ is the residue.

Thus you need to compute
$$
\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{z-\pi}{\sin z}=\lim_{w\to0}\frac{w}{\sin(w+\pi)}=\lim_{w\to0}-\frac{w}{\sin w}=-1
$$

Comment: Many thanks, clear solution

Answer (score 0):

If $z=z_0$ -- it's a simple pole (simple zero of the denominator and non-zero of the numerator), then you can use the formula $\text{res}_{z=z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$.