# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find residue of function $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$ at $z=0$. I got a hint that I needed to use derivative but I don't know exactly how.

I used Euler's formula $\sin \pi z =\frac{ e^{i\pi z} - e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}$
to find the residue of $\frac{1}{\sin \pi z}$. Now I have to calculate the residue of $\frac{1}{\sin \pi z}$ but I don't know how.

Comment: See that answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496164/compute-the-residue-of-1-sin-z-at-z-pi/3496179#3496179

Comment: That residue is just $$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z}{\sin{(\pi z)}}=\frac1\pi$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Where do we get the z on the top side of fraction? (I don't know what it's called in English)

Comment: The pole of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is a simple pole hence the residue is just $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)$

Comment: The $z$ on the top side of fraction it's called _numerator_

Comment: The residue of $f(z)$ at $a$ equals $\lim_\limits {z\to a} (z-a)f(z)$