# Find Residues About Specific Points

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w=1/\sin(z)$.
As I understand it, the singular point will be the point $\pi$, which is a simple pole. If so, can it be decomposed as follows?

$$\operatorname{res}(f)=\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{1}{\sin⁡(z)}=\frac{1}{\sin⁡'(π)}=\frac{1}{\cos⁡(π)}=1.$$

Comment: There are *many* singular points, not just $\pi$: for each integer $n$, $n\pi$ is a pole of $1/\sin(z)$.

Comment: As @KCd mentioned, there are many singular points for $f(z)=1/\sin(z)$. Regarding the residue of $f$ at $\pi$, you need to compute $\lim_{z\rightarrow\pi} (z-\pi)/\sin(z)$, which is equal to $-1$. This has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496164/compute-the-residue-of-1-sin-z-at-z-pi.

Comment: @KCd then can i write like this 2πn+πn 
and it will essential singularity?

Comment: The function $1/\sin(z)$ has no essential singularities. When $f(z)$ is an entire function, $1/f(z)$ is meromorphic: where it is not finite, it has poles rather than essential singularities.